# How to change themes using SASS

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a website built on SASS. There're certain variables I want to change while switching between light and dark themes, but all variables get compiled and converted to its original value. Hence, I don't know how to change SASS variables while changing themes.

Assuming I have following variables in `style.scss`:

```
$mainColor: #eaeaea;
$secondaryColor: #fff;

$mainText: black;
$secondaryText: #2a3a47;

$borderColor: #c1c1c1;

$themeDotBorder: #24292e;

$previewBg: rgba(251, 249, 243, 0.8);
$previewShadow: #f9ead6;
$buttonColor: #0a0a0a;
```

How do I change these variables while switching themes. I can create two separate css files but that would be redundant code. Can you help me?

Comment: what are your requirements for browsers?

Comment: I want it to work on all browsers

Comment: well IE11 as well? Are you using postcss? What kind of build process do you have for sass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your build process and requirements for older browsers, for example ie11.

Themes becomes easier with css custom properties (css variables). The basic idea is that you have your variables, and on theme change you change the color of the variables.

In my very very basic example the following things happen and why.

1. On root level set your variables for your default theme.
2. Have a class with the describing the theme, in my example it is `.dark-theme`
3. Set a class on the body when dark-theme is active with js, or postback depending on your backend and wanted approach. In my example I do it with js.

What happens here is that in `.dark-theme` we change the variables to the dark theme colors. That is the basics of it and will get you far.

Just a note, the approach on saving the theme all depends on what kind of site you have SPA, Wordpress, .NET ect. I seen mentions about saving it in the database and user, that kinda don't hold up if you don't have user signing. One approach is to save it in the browsers local storage and read it when you load the page.

```js
const themeSwitcherButton = document.querySelector('.js-theme-switcher')

themeSwitcherButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const body = document.querySelector('body')
  
  if (body.classList.contains('dark-theme')) {
    body.classList.remove('dark-theme')
  } else {
    body.classList.add('dark-theme')
  }
})
```

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: deepskyblue;
}

body.dark-theme {
  --primary-color: deeppink;
}


.block {
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p class="block">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima quos odio atque excepturi, aut voluptate. Similique autem, eos rem cum tenetur perspiciatis voluptatibus reprehenderit cumque, inventore, nam laudantium fugiat molestias eveniet sit commodi deleniti. Ipsa eum animi, excepturi tempore placeat.
  </p>
  
  <button class="js-theme-switcher">Theme switcher</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you @Dejan, this is amazing approach

Comment: I just noticed that `body.dark-theme {
  $mainColor: purple;
  $secondaryText: #fff;
}` doesn't work. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @DarioushPD you use scss variables, you should be using css custom properties, declared `--secondaryText: #fff`

Answer (score -1):

use css variables instead of sass one

```
--mainColor: #eaeaea;
```

and

```
color: var(--mainColor);
```

to use it

**edit:**

to change dynamically css variables

```
var bodyStyles = document.body.style;
bodyStyles.setProperty('--mainColor', 'white');
```

if variables was declared on body element

Comment: This does not answer the question, you just state to use a variable but not how to actually use it for a theme. Also you don't ask if the OP needs for browser support, what is your fallback for browsers not supporting it?

Comment: Not to pick on you but why do you use Javascript?

Comment: @Dejan.S I know that there is better way with classes contains variables but how to to that without js?

Comment: You can see my example. They way you describe works for the demo you state here, what if you need to change --mainColor on 200+ classes? It won't hold up that good.